# Find all the possible values of $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-problem

a) Let $D = \{z\in\mathbb{C}: z \neq \pm i\}$ and let $\gamma$ be a closed contour in D. Find all the possible values of $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$.

b) If $\sigma$ is a contour from  0 to 1,, find all possible values of $\int_{\sigma} \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$

I am stuck on a) I am not sure which $\gamma$ to choose. (I cannot use the Residue theorem, I did not learn it yet)

but for b) I chose $\sigma(t) = t$ for $t \in [0,1]$ which then when I solved the integral I got $\int_{\sigma} \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz = \pi/4$

Comment: You don't get to choose $\gamma$, do you? You have to find all possible values of the integral - there will multiple different values depending on what $\gamma$ is, no? So, do you have the residue theorem at hand?

Comment: @runway44 perhaps, not that is why I am stuck. I am doing this problem without knowledge of Residue Theorem

Comment: @pop Part a) requires the Residue Theorem. Why do you say you cannot use it?

Comment: @ndhanson3 I did not learn it yet

Comment: Where is this problem from? I expect the author of the problem expects the reader to use the residue theorem, since it seems unavoidable...

Comment: Well, it is easily answered with the Residue Theorem, and I believe cannot be answered fully without it. Part b) uses the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (or maybe called Fundamental Theorem of Complex Line Integrals).

Comment: For part a, consider a few cases: where $\gamma$ encloses none, each individually, or both of the singularities of the integrand

Comment: @runway44 The textbook is Complex Analysis Second Edition by Ian Stewart and David Tall. The Residue Theorem is mentioned 4 chapters later than this problem

Comment: Partial fractions is your friend. And homotopy.

Comment: @pop Ah, winding number is presented separately. You'll use the theorem relating the integral over closed contours to the points outside of the domain $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\frac1{z^2+1}=\frac{i/2}{z+i}-\frac{i/2}{z-i}.$$So,$$\oint_\gamma\frac1{z^2+1}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i\left(\frac i2\operatorname{ind}_\gamma(-i)-\frac i2\operatorname{ind}_\gamma(i)\right).$$Since each of the numbers $\operatorname{ind}_\gamma(-i)$ and $\operatorname{ind}_\gamma(i)$ can be any integer, $\oint_\gamma\frac1{z^2+1}\,\mathrm dz$ can be any integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: how did you go from the integral to the right hand side?

Comment: I used the definition of winding number:$$\operatorname{ind}_\gamma(a)=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a}.$$